# VS Code TypeScript SourceMap creation

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I've installed newest Version of VS Code and I try to compile a "app.ts" file so that I get a "app.js" and "app.js.map". But when I compile the project it only creates the "app.js" file and no mapping file.

in my root folder I've a ".vscode" folder with the following "tsconfig.json"

```
{
 "compilerOptions": {
     "target": "es6",
     "module": "amd",
     "sourceMap": true 
}
```

and the following the "tasks.json" file

```
{
   "version": "0.1.0",

   // The command is tsc. Assumes that tsc has been installed using npm install -g typescript
   "command": "tsc",

   // The command is a shell script
   "isShellCommand": true,

   // Show the output window only if unrecognized errors occur.
   "showOutput": "silent",

   // args is the HelloWorld program to compile.
   "args": ["app.ts"],

   // use the standard tsc problem matcher to find compile problems
   // in the output.
   "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
   }
}
```

and in the root directory I've my "app.ts" file

```
module App {
    export class Person {
        constructor(public name: string) { }

        public log(showLog: boolean): void {
            if (showLog) {
                console.log("Der Name des Nutzers ist: " + this.name)
            }
        }
    }
}

var person = new App.Person("Hallo Welt");
person.log(true);
```

but when I compile it with ctrl+shift+b it only creates the app.js file and no mapping.

Update:
I've also tried to modify the "tasks.json"

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",

    // The command is tsc. Assumes that tsc has been installed using npm install -g typescript
    "command": "tsc",

    // The command is a shell script
    "isShellCommand": true,

    // Show the output window only if unrecognized errors occur.
    "showOutput": "always",

    // args is the HelloWorld program to compile.
    "args": [" --sourcemap app.ts"],

    // use the standard tsc problem matcher to find compile problems
    // in the output.
    "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
}
```

with --sourcemap Argument but it doesn't work. But when I use the command promt with the following command:

```
c:\Temp\vsCode\tsc --sourcemap app.ts
```

then everything works fine and the mapping files are created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Solution: modify the args, its an array with strings, seems to be one solution

```
"args": ["--sourcemap", "app.ts"]
```

alternate Solution, when you want to use your tsconfig.json for compile options you need to use this task.json entry:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",

    // The command is tsc. Assumes that tsc has been installed using npm install -g typescript
    "command": "tsc",

    // The command is a shell script
    "isShellCommand": true,

    // Show the output window only if unrecognized errors occur.
    "showOutput": "silent",

    "windows": {
        "command": "tsc",
        "isShellCommand": true
    },

    // Tell the tsc compiler to use the tsconfig.json from the open folder.
    "args": ["-p", "."],

    // use the standard tsc problem matcher to find compile problems
    // in the output.
    "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
}
```

I've modified the original post and added the "windows" Settings, without this settings it seems that vs code uses a old typescript version 1.0.3.0 but I don't know why.

Solution Number 3 - Try to look if the Windows PATH variable don't has a entry to TypeScript Version 1.0 - remove this entry and add a entry to the newest version

Answer (score 2):

I think you should have tsconfig.json in the root folder (see [tsconfig](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/tsconfig.json)). Not in the .vscode folder.

.vscode folder is ment for storing config files that are specific to visual sudio code (launch.json, settings.json, tasks.json).

Comment: I've tried it with the same result no mapping file is created